# Unwrap Tuple or keep it as it is?

Tags: c#, performance, tuples

Is it faster to process the unwrapping of `Tuple` and using a few variables instead of just using `Tuple` as it is. 
Consider this example :

```
Tuple<int,int> test = new Tuple<int,int>;

int numberOne = int.Parse(Console.Readline());
int numberTwo = int.Parse(Console.Readline());

test.Item1 = numberOne;
test.Item2 = numberTwo;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if(test.Item1 * i > test.Item2 * i)
    {// do stuff}
    else
    {// do stuff}
}
```

VS

```
Tuple<int,int> test = new Tuple<int,int>;

int numberOne = int.Parse(Console.Readline());
int numberTwo = int.Parse(Console.Readline());

test.Item1 = numberOne;
test.Item2 = numberTwo;

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++)
{
    int tempItem1 = test.Item1;
    int tempItem2 = test.Item2;

    if(tempItem1 * i > tempItem2 * i)
    {// do stuff}
    else
    {// do stuff}
}
```

I also want to know if  unwrapping the `Tuple` with 2 variables is faster than using item1 and item2. Will the result still be the same if we were using more than 2 variables ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Worrying about the difference in performance at this level is completely pointless. Write code that is easiest to understand when you come back to it/pass it on to the next person. When you have performance issues, take measurements, then decide how to optimize. Ninety nine times out of a hundred, it won't be in the place you expect. Stop worrying about "what's fastest", and instead concentrate on the correctness and "understandability" of your code. You're concentrating on [micro-optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)...

Comment: But that's not even my code i just wrote it here i was wondering if it actually matters

Comment: IMO Tuples are an unfriendly data type that don't capture any meaning in the property name, so it will add clarity to your code by creating a local variable with a good name that points to a Tuple property (for instance `var numberOfItems = someTuple.Item1;`). It's exceedingly unlikely that the cost of the extra local variable will significantly slow down your program unless it's in a hot section of the code that is called in the order of millions of times. When your program runs slow, use profiling to find out where the cost is. I'll bet it isn't borne by assigning a couple of local variables

Comment: Tuple is defined as a class, not a struct, so it will require a heap allocation to create, and it will have to follow the pointer to the heap every time you use it, so it will be a lot slower compared to local stack variables.  Whether that matters is probably something you need to use a profiler to figure out, since the allocation will be small and fairly fast, and the dereferencing cost will usually be hidden by CPU pre-fetch unless you are running this on a machine that typically is at 100% CPU utilization.

Comment: When you ask perf questions about imaginary code then you will get imaginary answers.  If perf matters then use your own struct.  Does not hurt readability either.

Comment: Most likely the compiler will generate the nearly the same IL code for both examples.  If you write code that does nothing other than populating a variable for comparison instead of comparing the original example, it'll probably be compiled away.  Something like `var result = 1 + 1; return result;` the result variable is just simply not needed and is compiled into `return 1 + 1;` (at a bar minimum).  That being said, write read-able code is fair superior to fast code until you actually have a performance problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both versions load the tuple items from memory into a temporary value. The only difference is whether it's a temporary on the IL execution stack or an actual IL local. Normally, this should be within reach of the JIT.

If this was a C compiler it would be 100% certain that the performance is the same. Any case where that was not so would be a bug.

The .NET JIT has a very poor optimizer so you might always get unlucky and step into an optimizer hole.

Comment: Poor?  What is poor about the .Net Jit Comiler/Runtime?

Comment: The JIT is not a very sophisticated optimizer when you consider that 100s of millions of .NET app servers are running it. The Hotspot JVM is by far more sophisticated.

Comment: So basically your argument for performance is that 100s of millions of app servers run it. Based on your JVM comment, I'll have to state you're just making a Genetic Logical Fallacy and without any type of concrete examples it just seems like your making false accusations.

Comment: You seem to have the opposite opinion with the same strength and the same lack of arguments. That's no better.; I have created an extensive JIT testsuite of about 80 tests and investigated code gen to compare the old and the new JIT in detail. To give an example how poor the JIT is: When you say `a.x + a.x` this loads x twice from memory. At this point *Really* basic things are not being optimized. (The new JIT has some nice suprises as well to be fair. But code gen is very unsophisticated across the board.) @ErikPhilips